# Why do I have to put a ternary operator expression in brackets inside a boolean check?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, boolean-logic

If I have a two part boolean check like `A && B` without any use of `||` then I'd expect that the check is immediately false if A is false. However, if B is a ternary operator, this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
    var foo = false
        && false ? true : true;
```

`foo` is **true** in this example, presumably because the (&& ternary) part somehow functions more like ||. If I surround the ternary check with brackets however, it works as expected:

```
    var bar = false
        && (false ? true : true);
```

`bar` is **false** in this example.

What is the reason/explanation for this behaviour? Why do I have to surround a ternary operator and the resulting expressions in brackets inside a boolean check?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019 - && is higher precedence than ?:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the order of evaluation, that is altered using parentheses. The first code is actually:

```
var foo = (false && false) ? true : true;
```

Which means:

```
if (false&&false)
 foo=true;
else
 foo=true;
```

The second is:

`var bar = false && (false ? true : true);`

Which means

```
bool x    
if (false)
 x=true;
else
 x=true;
if (false&&x)
 bar=true;
else
 bar=false;
```

One pair of parentheses changes everything.

Answer (score 4):

The first actually can be read like

```
var foo = (false && false) ? true : true;
```

Comment: *facepalm*, I think, covers it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to use parenthesis because the ternary operator (`c ? t : f`) has lower precedence compared to the conditional and operator (`x && y`) so when you combine them the precedence acts like "invisible" parenthesis:

```
(x && y) ? t : f
```

You can see all the operators listed by precedence in the section [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) in the C# reference on Microsoft Docs.